# SAP Hybris on Mac OS Catalina

Tags: java, tomcat, sap-commerce-cloud

I just update my Mac OS to Catalina version and my Hybris server stopped turning on. So on command ./hybrisserver.sh start I get this

> MacBook-Pro-Sasha:platform sashayukhimchuk$ ./hybrisserver.sh start
>       Starting hybrisPlatform on Tomcat...
>       /Users/sashayukhimchuk/hybris/CXCOMM181100P_1-70004085/hybris/bin/platform/tomcat/bin/wrapper.sh:
>   line 1388:  4614 Killed: 9
>   "/Users/sashayukhimchuk/hybris/CXCOMM181100P_1-70004085/hybris/bin/platform/tomcat/bin/./wrapper-macosx-universal-64"
>   "/Users/sashayukhimchuk/hybris/CXCOMM181100P_1-70004085/hybris/bin/platform/tomcat/conf/wrapper.conf"
>   wrapper.syslog.ident="hybrisPlatform"
>   wrapper.pidfile="/Users/sashayukhimchuk/hybris/CXCOMM181100P_1-70004085/hybris/bin/platform/tomcat/bin/hybrisPlatform.pid"
>   wrapper.daemonize=TRUE wrapper.name="hybrisPlatform"
>   wrapper.displayname="hybrisPlatform on Tomcat"
>   wrapper.statusfile="/Users/sashayukhimchuk/hybris/CXCOMM181100P_1-70004085/hybris/bin/platform/tomcat/bin/hybrisPlatform.status"
>   wrapper.java.statusfile="/Users/sashayukhimchuk/hybris/CXCOMM181100P_1-70004085/hybris/bin/platform/tomcat/bin/hybrisPlatform.java.status" wrapper.script.version=3.5.29 --
>       Waiting for hybrisPlatform on Tomcat..................
>       WARNING: hybrisPlatform on Tomcat may have failed to start.

Comment: somehow  ./hybrisserver.sh debug worked for me instead

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had to allow the `wrapper-macosx-universal-64` and some other libs in Systemsettings > Security > General while starting the Hybris Server.

Comment: For new version in MacOS it's in ```Privacy & Security > Security```

Answer (score 6):

Remove the app (and all the necesary side apps) from Mac OS quarantine:

```
xattr -d com.apple.quarantine wrapper-macosx-universal-64
```

You can find the blocked wrapper under /bin/platform/tomcat/bin

Answer (score 5):

If you get an error saying that the `wrapper-macosx-universal-64` or `libwrapper-macosx-universal-64.jnilib` cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified, proceed as follows:

1. Go to system preferences security and privacy
2. Click the General tab.
3. In the list, select the executable that you tried to run, and unblock it.

Run the command again.

Answer (score 1):

to fix it, u need new tomcat in bin/platform. I just create new hybris project with .zip and copy tomcat folder to my hybris project and after some confirming about security in Mac OS setting, it works

Answer (score 0):

It's probably could happen as a result that wrapper-macosx-universal-64 was deleted by macOS during a security check.

You can copy the file from the original path in hybris zip archive -

hybris-dir/bin/platform/tomcat/wrapper-macosx-universal-64

to your installation and follow the actions related to macos developers security check to allow starting the tomcat

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Go to: System Settings -> Privacy & Security > Security (click on "Allow Anyway" button)

[image]